# How to build Mobile App for MDM Distribution

Tags: android, ios, mdm, android-enterprise, apple-business-manager

My company has an App which is already available on Apple & Android App stores. Now the requirement is to distribute these Apps to Some Organizations via MDM. This can be done by Customer at their end.

Before we tell our customers to consume the App using MDM we have to make sure about

1. Our mobile App will work with All the MDM's customers are using, how to test that?
2. The SSO authentication inside our App will work within MDM environment or now we have to use MDM authentiction tokens
3. Do we need to make any changes to our mobile App for MDM?

I searched internet for the above answers, but not able to find any relevant article or post. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If your app is on the app stores then the MDM just tells the device to install the app. There is nothing special you need to do. MDM doesn't do anything to the app or authentication. You can choose to support [appconfig](https://www.appconfig.org/) if there are settings that you think an organisation might want to control via MDM.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My confusion is how to test that before customer uses our App through MDM? Also MDM already authenticate against AD, can we use that token instead again do the authentication inside App?

Comment: No, the user typically authenticates to the MDM in order to install the management profile, and this may often be backed by AD but there is no ongoing authentication and the MDM doesn't provide single sign on. Some MDMs provide an enterprise sso capability that works with iOS's authentication extension capability https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/301

Comment: There are cloud based MDMs that offer free trials. You could use one of those to test installing your app